# Точное время ProgressBar

Tags: android-studio, java, android, progress-bar

Добрый день/вечер. Я новичок, первый раз пишу на Android.

Хочу установить точное время прокрутки Progress Bar'а в проекте, а после прокрутки - перейти на следующий xml-файл. Не знаю как.

Прописал в xml-файле:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="100"/>
```

Java-класс оставил пустым. Манифест заполнил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Точное время прокрутки

Вангую: Это значит время одного оборота анимации ProgressBar? Если да, то это слишком сложно для вашего уровня, проще будет найти картинку, как фон у прогрессбара, и поворачивать ее.

> перейти на следующий xml-файл\

Перейти на следующий XML файл нельзя. Потому что xml файлы не являются сущьностями, на которые можно перейти. Они служат всего лишь для разметки View. "Перейти" можно на другую Activity, например. Как? Гугл знает.

В общем, все очень плохо. Тут не любят такие глупые вопросы. А чтобы их не возникало, прежде чем делать что-то свое, пройдите базовый курс Java и Android.

Comment: @metalurgus, окей, буду гуглить. Спасибо, что ответили.